# How to use CoffeeScript instead of JSON? For configuration files etc

Tags: json, node.js, coffeescript

JSON really is a pain to use for local configuration files as it does not support comments or functions, and requires incredibly verbose syntax (commas, always use `"` for keys). Making it very error prone, or in the case where functions are required, impossible to use.

Now I know that I could just do:

```
require('coffee-script')
config = require('config.coffee')
```

However, that requires me to do `module.exports = {the data}` inside `config.coffee` which is less than ideal. And even allows for things such as `require` to be exposed which can make the configuration files insecure if we do not trust them.

Has anyone found a way to read coffeescript configuration files, but keep them secure?

Comment: It's hard to tell whether this question was asked in earnest, given that the library you mention in your reply is months old.

Comment: @LinusGThiel why would the age of the library diminish the usefulness of it in solving a problem? or rather, diminish the usefulness of me posting it to save time for other developers whom are experiencing the same problem?

Comment: I flagged your question as spam -- "This question is effectively an advertisement with no disclosure. It is not useful or relevant, but promotional." I have nothing against coffeescript or CSON, and I think your library is interesting. But I dislike dishonesty, and this question/answer dance is a theater.

Comment: @LinusGThiel I'm really confused about what your distain is. I don't get paid for having reputation, I don't get paid for the open-source CSON library. I post this, and I create open-source libraries, to save time for others. There is nothing I have not disclosed about these honest intentions. It seems you have a different feeling about my actions, and are finding ways to back that up, rather than understand my own perception. I feel my actions here completely align with stack exchange's opinion on the matter: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: I regret my previous stance, I understand your perception, I commend you for your library, I apologize deeply, I stand corrected, and I feel slightly ashamed. Unfortunately I cannot unflag the question, so I have voted it (along with your excellent answer) up. Sorry man.

Comment: @LinusGThiel wow... that is so truly commendable, thank you. If you don't mind, I'd love to understand a bit more about the cause of your original stance and the cause of the change? As personally I believe everyone always has good intentions and that bad intentions are just misunderstandings, so would it'd be to cool to understand where the misunderstanding came from :). Again, it takes a person of great courage to do what you just did, thank you :)

Comment: I felt it dishonest of you to post a question which you already knew the answer to, and proceed to write the answer as if you just figured it out, while knowing all the time that you had the solution. After reading your linked blog post, I now know that this is encouraged on SO, and I can see why it helps. To repent, I sent a pull request to bevry/cson so you can `require()` a CSON file. :-)

Comment: :) awesome! and good to know. Again, thanks so much, and thanks for the pull request :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out CoffeeScript has support for the security part built in via setting the `sandbox` argument to `true` via the `eval` call. E.g.

```
# Prepare
fsUtil = require('fs')
coffee = require('coffee-script')

# Read
dataStr = fsUtil.readFileSync('path').toString()
data = coffee.eval(dataStr, {sandbox:true})
```

The above code will read in the file data, then eval it with coffeescript in sandbox mode.

I've created a nice wrapper for this called [CSON](https://github.com/bevry/cson) which supports `coffee` and `js` files via require, and `cson` files via the above mechanism, and `json` files via the typical `JSON.parse` - as well as stringifying the values back to coffeescript notation. Using this, the following API is exposed:

```
# Include CSON
CSON = require('cson')

# Parse a file path
CSON.parseFile 'data.cson', (err,obj) ->  # async
result = CSON.parseFile('data.cson')  # sync

# Parse a string
CSON.parse src, (err,obj) ->  # async
result = CSON.parseSync(src)  # sync

# Stringify an object to CSON
CSON.stringify data, (err,str) ->  # async
result = CSON.stringifySync(obj)  # sync
```

Comment: Awesome!! Just what I was looking for